# Do I need business objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm learning to program using C# and ASP.NET with a SQL Server database. I have developed a system to store and view trades taken on a financial market. Basic functionality is:

- Add/Update/Delete an Order
- Add/Update/Delete a Trade (a trade comprises one or more orders)
- View trades
- View orders

There are other entities as well, things like Brokers, Accounts, Strategies, etc that support the main Order and Trade entities.

I have designed my program to have a Database utility class called `DBUtil` which has all the interfaces to the database. For example to add a new trade I would call `DBUtil.InsertTrade(<params>)`, to add an order `DBUtil.InsertOrder(<params>)`, to update a trade, `DBUtil.UpdateTrade(<params>)`, etc. I was wondering if it would be better to create a Trade class, an Order class, a Broker class, etc. Would that improve the elegance, quality and maintainability of the program? It seems like adding a lot more code for no benefit, well, I can't see the benefits right now of taking such an approach.

As far as I can see adding a `Trade` class would simply create an extra layer of code, because I would have to call `DBUtil.InsertTrade()` from the Trade class anyway when adding a trade, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what the application will grow into and who will maintain it.

IF you are happy with it at the minute then why change it.

I would advise you to read up on software development patterns, at the minute it sounds like you are using the Active Record pattern, and that is OK:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern

What you are thinking of is moving to a Domain Driven Design solution.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design

Comment: Thanks, so for the `Trade` object, what public and private methods would I have? I guess I would write something like `Trade t = new Trade(string market, etc)`? And then do something `t.Save()` to save to the DB?

Comment: OK, another quick Q, what if I want to return all Trades filtered by some criteria. Would I have to do `Trade t = new Trade(); t.GetTrades(<params>);`? Or is there a better, cleaner way? The semantics feels wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will improve the maintainability of your code because your business objects will be strongly typed. In addition to that you can create a test scenario without having to connect to real database using mockup of your business objects. One of disadvantages is more code have to be written of course but it will benefit you in the future expansion of your application.

Usually if you use Linq2Sql or EF, VS can create these classes for you.

Edit:
See also this question [Why do we need a business logic layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318216/why-we-need-business-logic-layer)

Answer (score 0):

Yes Domain object will be usefull for this case.